# Nodejs - mysql2 stream connection and remote host

Tags: node.js, node-mysql2

I need to query a mysql database from one server. The mysql database is located on another network. I can only connect to this network from a specific server.

I need to create a tunnel from server 1, into server 2 and use this tunnel to connect to my mysql database.

This is my current code. This allows me to connect to server 2's local mysql server, but not to a remote mysql server.

```
var Client = require('ssh2').Client,
mysql = require('mysql2'),

var client = new Client();
var ssh = client.connect({
  host: config.server_tunnel.dstHost,
  port: 22,
  username: config.server_tunnel.username,
  privateKey: config.server_tunnel.privateKey
});

ssh.forwardOut('127.0.0.1', 12345, '127.0.0.1', 3306, function (err, stream) {
   mysql.createConnection({
    user: config.database.username,
    password: config.database.password,
    database: config.database.database,
    stream: stream,
    host: 'remote.host.com'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing `host` to `mysql.createConnection()`, try making the tunnel connect to it:

```
ssh.forwardOut('127.0.0.1', 12345, 'remote.host.com', 3306, ...);
```

Comment: Perfect, that makes total sense now you've pointed it out. Thank you.